# React Native Expo - how to get local uri to user's media library from image picker

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-image-picker, media-library

I can't find how one would get (using expo packages) the local uri like `file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/...` from user picking an image from their media library without having to re-save/duplicate the image.

This gives me a paginated structure of user's photos and contains the uri I'd expect:

```
await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
    mediaType: [
        'photo',
    ],
});
```

However that does not open the media library, what does is:

```
await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePickerExpo.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
    presentationStyle: 0,
});
```

However uri here is something like `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/...` which looks to me like an uri to a temporary cache, not the permanent uri to the local file.

**Is there a way how to get the permanent media library uri from the image picker?**
(Without having to basically create your own gallery and picker using the `getAssetsAsync()` ?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code! so help you!

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
const info = await MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(item.id)
const uri_local = info.localUri;
item.uri = uri_local;
console.log("test image: ", info)
}
else if (Platform.OS === 'android') 
{
                
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).